# AKS External IP is not working

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-devops

I have been working in CICD to AKS from VSTS and deployed to AKS, & later it exposed an External Ip .

When I browse it , I

[Fiddler] The connection to 'IP' failed. 
Error: TimedOut (0x274c). 
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond IP:80

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KhQ15.png)

Comment: Could you show more information about it? information about load balancer rules, your k8s pod file.

Comment: Does it work now?

Comment: Hey @JasonYe-MSFT . No . Its not working.

Comment: Could you show me more information about your AKS and pods?

Comment: Could you run this command `kubectl get services` to list your services and public ip address?

Comment: I was able to fix the issue. Issue was my PODS in AKS are not in running state, and Unable to authenticate with ACR. I had to create a secret in AKS and use in my Deploy.YML file (Image pull secret as secret name.) And later pods are running , able to access with External IP

Comment: Glad to hear that your issue has been resolved. Could you please post your detailed solution to this issue as an answer so that other community members will be benefited.